# Is it possible to use the values() method on arrays?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For some reason, whenever I apply the values() method on an array, I get a TypeError. Even when I copy the [code examples directly from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values). For example:

```
var a = ['w', 'y', 'k', 'o', 'p']; 
var iterator = a.values();
```

However, the keys() method works fine. I can also apply values() on maps and sets without any problem.
I tried the code on the latest version of Chrome and Firefox and both throw a TypeError. What am I missing?

Edit:
It looks like this method is not implemented on FireFox 58 and Chrome 64. Only works on FF 60 nightly and CH 66.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by applying values method on array?

Comment: go to `chrome://version` and make sure it is past 66. Not sure about firefox

Comment: if you want an iterator, then use `a.entries();`.

Comment: @florent b. thats missing the point

Comment: Seems like its browser support is not that well...

Comment: The browser compatibility table shows you version numbers of the supported browsers, so that's the first thing to look at.

Comment: Yeah, if you log the array and view the prototype, it is not defined for me on Chrome 64.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 60. Please specify the versions of the browsers you’re using, and the exact error message. (And look at the compatibility table at the bottom of the MDN page you linked.)

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, It looks like this method is not implemented on FF 58 and Chrome 64. Only works on FF 60 and CH 66.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question of browser support...

Answer (score 0):

[The very same document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) clearly states which browsers support `Array.prototype.values`. It's supported in latest versions of evergreen browsers.

The support in recent browser version (e.g. 64 vs. 66) shouldn't be a concern in web development. Polyfills are necessary in modern JS application, and `values` is polyfillable feature. It can be polyfilled with core.js or polyfill.io to be supported in any modern browser.